# Difficulty using array in object oriented programming in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, oop

I want to extract data from MySQL database based on multiple conditions but my action function allows me to extract data based only on 1 condition.

Please help me to modify action function so that i can use multiple array to extract data.

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->error = false;
    if ($this->query = $this->pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if (count($params)) {
            foreach ($params as $param) {
                $this->query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }
        if ($this->query->execute()) {
            $this->results = $this->query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->count = $this->query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->error = true;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
    if (count($where === 3)) {
        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

        $field = $where[0];
        $operator = $where[1];
        $value = $where[2];

        if (in_array($operator, $operators)) {
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

            if (!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                return $this;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function get($table, $where) {
    return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
}
```

Comment: That's about the worst possible design for a db abstraction layer you could come up with. `action`? Good luck with that when you try to use `update`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In object-orienter ORM layers it's common to have a separate class for a statement, or, more specifically, for SELECT statements, e.g.

```
$users = $db->select('*')
   ->from('users')
   ->where('id', '>', 100)
   ->where('name', 'like', 'agg%')
   ->orderBy('name')
   ->execute()
   ->getResults();
```

It would be a great learning exercise to design a class that allows something like that.

Comment: I am new to OOP, can you please help me elaborate your ans so that i can easily understand it

Comment: @aggarwal: this is called ["fluent interface"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#PHP). Basically, you create an object and use methods to set its properties. Each such method returns `$this`, thus allowing for further chaining.